# jQuery if/else on click

Tags: jquery

On clicking .class I would like to execute orangeBarClick above #id else I would like to show orangeBar:

```
<div class="class">
Click this.
</div>
<div #spl-footer>
Insert before this setence.
</div>

var orangeBar = '<div>Default</div>';
var orangeBarClick = '<div>OnClick</div>';                          

if ($('.click').data('clicked')) {
$(orangeBarClick).insertBefore("#spl-footer");
      } else {
 $(orangeBar).insertBefore("#spl-footer");
 });
```

I don't think I have written the if/else statement correctly though as it does not execute. What am I missing here? https://jsfiddle.net/q0536q3h/

Comment: Can you post your HTML code too? I don't see any CSS class, named class in your code.

Comment: `.data()` method is not an event method, use `.click`. Your conditional on the other hand can use `.data()`, but your HTML must have an element with the `data-clicked` attribute. `class` is a reserved keyword so **never** name anything by the word `class`. You need to know some fundamentals https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: @zer00ne Though yes you should probably not name something `.class` its completely valid to give elements the class name `.class`. And grabbing it with `$('.class')` will not cause any issues, minus some confusion and dirty looks from other developers. In this instance I'm pretty sure op is just using `.class` and `#id` as examples.

Comment: I have updated the code. When 'Click this' sentence is clicked, I would like var orangeBarClick to display again before #spl-footer. If not's not clicked by default I would like var organeBar to be displayed instead. Hopefull this clarifies it.

Comment: @Sam I know, but if you scare someone from a bad habit it won't lead to worser things like `class()` :P

Comment: Why don't you just make it equal to the default HTML in your actual HTML code? And then when ever it is clicked, change it. There's no point setting that default in JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Please try again #   

 <div class="click">Click this.</div>
<div id="spl-footer">Insert before this setence.</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

var orangeBar = '<div>Default</div>';
var orangeBarClick = '<div>OnClick</div>';                          

//var isClicked = jQuery('.click').data('clicked');
//alert(isClicked);

$('.click').on('click', function() {
  var isClicked = $(this).data('clicked', 'yes');
  if(isClicked[0].className == 'click'){
    $(orangeBarClick).insertBefore("#spl-footer");
  }else{
    $(orangeBar).insertBefore("#spl-footer");
  }
});
</script>
```